# how to update the url in md-editor-v3 callback vue3

Tags: callback, vuejs3, vue-component

I have a vue template that uses the md-editor-v3 component (https://github.com/imzbf/md-editor-v3?tab=readme-ov-file)

I tried to implement the onUploadImage method, but the callback function does not seem to work as the url stays undefined even though in the console I can see that the post to the backend returned the url where the file is stored.

```
<template>
    <MDEditor v-model="text" language="en-US" @onUploadImg="onUploadImg" />
</template>

<script>
    exportDefault {
      name: 'MyComponent'
      data() {
        return {}
      },
      methods: {
        async onUploadImg(files,callback,item,index) {
            const res = await Promise.all(
                Array.from(files).map((file) => {
                    return new Promise((rev, rej)=> {
                        const form = new FormData();
                        form.append('image', file);
                        axios.post('/upload', form, {
                            headers: {
                                'Content-Type' : 'multipart/form-data'
                            }
                        })
                        .then((res) => rev(res))
                        .catch((error) => rej(error));
                    });
                })
            );
            callback(res.map((item) => item.data.url));
         }
      }
    }
</script>
```

The image is correctly uploaded to the backend the backend correctly sends back the image url. the image is accessible if I put the url directly in the editor

but on the editor i get this[image: undefined url]

What do I do wrong?